# Linking two projects, other R.java not generated

Tags: android, project, manifest, android-resources, r.java-file

I have been writting an app that is bulid of two projects. They were working fine, but lately I moved my project to new computer and problems with linking these two occured. I moved them manualy, on pendrive, so I had to add all project imports again.

First there were problems with importing specyfic classes, but I have solved that by right-clicking on project -> Build path -> configure build path -> projects -> add and adding second project. Great, that worked. But that's not all.

Every time I try to get some resources from other project (for example using setTheme(R.style.someStyle) I receive error "someStyle cannot be resolvet or is not a field". I found out that is becouse Eclipse didn't generated second R.java in gen directory. I had that on my previous computer. After oppening gen there were two "packages", each containing R.java from other project. Now I have just one.

Do you know how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a new project and then copy all classes and resources from "src" and "res" folder to new project, then you can build your new project.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need two R.... anymore. Check your imports. You can find the resources merged in the only R class

Just an example, if not like yours, please give some more info:

Library:

[image: Embedded project (library)]

Image from R.java.id from App:

[image: Extracted R.java.id from embedding project(app)]

Comment: Actually no. They are not merged